# Maintaining a Pandas Dataframe primary sort order in a grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe seqdf

```
Country     Pattern
Hong Kong   abc 
Hong Kong   def
[...]
Australia   ghi
Australia   jkl
[...]
```

I want to get the most common patterns by country.

I do this:

```
        seqdf.groupby('Country'['Pattern'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)[:100]
```

But this has the effect of ordering the occurrences of pattern without keeping the Country grouping.    The output might look like:

```
Hong Kong  def    5101
Australia  jki    4888
Hong Kong  abc    3123  
Australia  efg    1882
[...]
```

How to keep the primary sort of country ascending in the output and then sort by pattern occurrences descending?

Comment: `value_counts` sort the result in descending order by default. Doesn't `seqdf.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts()` give you what you need?

Comment: @ Psidom - Yes - for some reason I had tacked on more stuff which messed up the output.  Your short solution is correct!

Comment: @Psidom is there a simple way to only report the top N patterns for each country, let's say the top 5?

Comment: You an chain another `groupby.head`. i.e. `df.groupby("Country")['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(5)`

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @Psidom if you make that the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value_counts` by default sort the result in descending order, so `groupby.value_counts` should do; If you need to view top n rows for each country, you can use `groupby.head` to take top n rows from each country:

*Example*:

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Country     Pattern
Hong Kong   def
Hong Kong   abc
Hong Kong   def
Hong Kong   ghi
Australia   ghi
Australia   jkl
Australia   jkl
Australia   abc
Australia   jkl"""), sep = "\s{2,}")
```

`groupby` country and do the value_counts results in series sorted by counts in descending order within each group:

```
df.groupby("Country")['Pattern'].value_counts()

#Country    Pattern
#Australia  jkl        3
#           abc        1
#           ghi        1
#Hong Kong  def        2
#           abc        1
#           ghi        1
#Name: Pattern, dtype: int64
```

To see top 5 items for each country which is the level 0 index, use `groupby.head`, this will take first n rows for each country:

```
df.groupby("Country")['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(2)

#Country    Pattern
#Australia  jkl        3
#           abc        1
#Hong Kong  def        2
#           abc        1
#Name: Pattern, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
seqdf.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts().to_frame('quantity').reset_index().sort_values(['Country', 'quantity'], ascending=[True, False])[:100]
```

To restrict to 10 patterns per country and get a plain DataFrame:

```
seqdf.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(10).to_frame('quantity').reset_index()
```

or like this:

```
seqdf.groupby(['Country', 'Pattern']).agg({'Pattern':'count'}).rename(columns={'Pattern':'quantity'}).groupby(level=0).head(10).reset_index().sort_values(['Country', 'quantity'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: It's ok:) I firstly thought that you wanted to sort by Country ascending and then by Pattern descending:)

Comment: That is the goal... when I ran your statement the Country was ordered properly but the column 'Quantity' was not descending.

Comment: I changed my solution to sort quantity descending. Maybe it helps later if you want to get a DataFrame instead of Series.